# Equivalence of Restricted Quantification as Compared to Conditionals in the Scope of the Quantifier

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Consider the following two propositions:

$$S_1 \subseteq S_2 := \forall x. x \in S_1 \implies x \in S_2$$

$$S_1 \subseteq S_2 := \forall x \in S_1. x \in S_2$$

These two expressions are used to denote the same thing and both often used to define the subset relation. But why is that so? Can the equivalence of these two expressions be demonstrated or is it just convention? Intuitively I would not agree that these say the same thing. $x$ being a member of $S_1$ does not in itself imply that $x$ is also a member of $S_2$. The second definition makes no mention of a logical consequence of $x$ necessarily having to be a member of $S_2$ when it is a member of $S_1$. It merely states that if both of these two things are the case, then $S_1$ is a subset of $S_2$.

So what justifies the implication and what makes these two statements equivalent in particular and what makes other pairs of statements that might be analogous (one involving an implication the other a restriction of the quantifier) equivalent, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the usual conventions (at least in axiomatic set theory), these two statements are the same *by definition*.  More precisely, the notation $$\forall x\in S. \varphi$$ is defined to be an abbreviation for $$\forall x.(x\in S\Rightarrow \varphi).$$  So your second statement is defined to mean your first statement.

Comment: Ah, ok. Is there a motivation to make a claim such as $x \in S_1 \implies x \in S_2$ too? As I wrote, intuitively I see no causal relationship between the two memberships here.

Comment: I think you are not understanding the intended intuitive interpretation of the notation "$\forall x \in S_1. x \in S_2$".  It is intended to be read "for any $x$ which is an element of $S_1$, $x$ is in $S_2$."  So for any $x$, if $x$ is an element of $S_1$, then that statement applies to $x$ and so $x$ is in $S_2$.  That is, $x\in S_1$ implies $x\in S_2$.

Comment: No no, I understand that. What I am saying is that I do not consider it obvious that "for any $x$ which is an element of $S_1$, $x$ is in $_2$." means the same thing as "for any $x$, $x$ is in $S_2$ if it is in $S_1$.", which is what $\forall x. x \in S_1 \implies x \in S_2$ means. In fact I'd say these two sentences do not say the same thing. But then how can the first one be the translation of what is just intended to be an abbreviation of the version with the implication arrow?

Comment: Can you give an example (specific $S_1$ and $S_2$) where the two statements seem intuitively inequivalent?

Comment: Well, what I wrote in my previous comment is an explanation for why "for any $x$ which is an element of $S_1$, $x$ is in $S_2$" implies "for any $x$, if $x$ is in $S_1$, then $x$ is in $S_2$".  The converse is similar.

Comment: Indeed "Anything that is in $S_1$, is in $S_2$" and "Anything will be in $S_2$ if it is in $S_1$" claim the exact same thing.